# Class "L5Swagger\Generation" not found

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

Whenever i run 'php artisan serve' i get the error "Class "L%Swagger\Generator" not found, Please i need a fix, really slowing me down

I've tried updating composer, tried downloading dependencies but i keep getting errors

Comment: The error should say something about *where* it's having trouble finding the class. What file is affected and why is it calling it?